# how to automatically replace a tag predefined

Tags: javascript, regex, vue.js, regex-group, regexp-replace

I have some characters that need to be replaced as above but I don't know how: 
characters to replace:

```
first   |  end  |
<day>   |       |
<red>   | </red>|
<a ###> | </>   |
```

`day           => get now day (ex: 14)`
`red           => color red` 
`<a ###https://www.google.com/>link</> => <a href="https://www.google.com/">link</>`

`input: hello <red>Mr.Siro</red>` 
`output: hello <span style="color: red">Mr.Siro</span>`

[my chat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hh6rb.png).

Can you show me how to write a common function to check the replacement of the above tags?
here is my code:

```js
export const formatTags = (content) => {
  const firstTag = "<red>";
  const secondTag = "</red>";

  const tagsIndex = [...content.matchAll(new RegExp(firstTag, "gi"))].map(
    (a) => a.index
  );

  const initialContent = content;

  tagsIndex.forEach((index) => {
    const tagContent = initialContent.substring(
      index + firstTag.length,
      initialContent.indexOf(secondTag, index)
    );

    if (firstTag === "<red>") {
      content = content.replaceAll(
        `${firstTag}${tagContent}${secondTag}`,
        `<span style="color: red">${tagContent || "わからない"}</span>`
      );
    }
  });

  return content;
};
```

```html
<span
   :class="(msg.image || msg.file) && msg.text ? 'mt-2' : ''"
   v-html="msg.text"
   v-linkified:options="{
    className: currentUserId === msg.senderId
     ? 'message-external-link'
     : '',
   }"
/>
```

sorry my english is not so good ! 
thanks all!

Comment: Is the input just a JS string, or is it in the markup?

Comment: `<a https://www.google.com/>link</>` is not a valid anchor. Do you mean `<a href="https://www.google.com">link</a>`?

Comment: Also, will it always be  `<red>*</red>` or can there be a `<blue>*</blue>` as well? Are there any other patterns other than mentioned in the question?

Comment: @Teemu input is a string: hello <red>hello<red> and is show by me through v-html in vuejs

Comment: @adiga there are many other styles like you say `<blue>, <yellow>, <green>...`

Comment: @adiga yes i mean `<a href="https://www.google.com">link</a>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a `Map` of the replacement rules. The regex used to capture the text will be the key and the replacer function callback to be used in `replace` will the value. Loop through the rules and update the string.

```js
const input = `Today is <day>th day of the month. 
I'd like <red> this text to be in red</red> 
and <blue>this to be in blue</blue>. 
Testing the links <a ###https://www.google.com/>with Google</>
and <a ###https://stackoverflow.com/>Stak Overflow</>`

function convert(str) {
  const replacerRules = new Map([
    [/<day>/g, new Date().getDate()],
    [/<([^>]+)>([^<]+)<\/\1>/g, (_, p1, p2) => `<span style="color: ${p1}">${p2}</span>`],
    [/<a #+([^>]+)>([^<]+)<\/>/g, (_, p1,p2) => `<a href="${p1}">${p2}</a>`]
  ])
  
  for (const [key, replacer] of replacerRules)
    str = str.replace(key, replacer)
  
  return str
}

console.log( convert(input) )
document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = convert(input)
```

```html
<div />
```

Comment: thank you i tried it and it worked, how do i change the path in href ?

Comment: Change in the `Map` object's value here ``<a href="https://www.google.com">${p1}</a>``

Comment: sorry i was mistaken, i meant `<a ###https://www.google.com/>link</>` not `<a ###>link</>` so please show me how to insert link after ### thanks you very much !

Comment: @hoangnv updated the third regex to get the URL from the text. That was not in the initial input

Comment: it worked beyond my expectations, thank you very much. but now there is a problem if i don't enter the value in the ex: `<red></red>` it prints a space `<red></red>`

Comment: @hoangnv You can probably change the second regex: `/<([^>]+)>([^<]+)<\/\1>/` to `/<([^>]+)>([^<]*)<\/\1>/` to make optional content within the tag. Please go through the regexes and test it out here: https://regex101.com/r/IkCZRB/1